# I can't get Bluetooth device list

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth, bluetooth-gatt

thank you very much for the project, I am using this dependancies. It will help me a lot! I have used below method to get bluetooth devices list can not get device list.

```
BleManager bleManager = BleManager.getInstance();
BleScanRuleConfig scanRuleConfig = new BleScanRuleConfig.Builder().setAutoConnect(false)
.setScanTimeOut(8000).build();
bleManager.initScanRule(scanRuleConfig);
BleManager.getInstance().scan(new BleScanCallback() {
@Override
public void onScanStarted(boolean success) {
Log.e(TAG, "onScanStarted");
}

            @Override
            public void onScanning(BleDevice bleDevice) {
                Log.e(TAG, "onScanning");
            }
    
            @Override
            public void onScanFinished(List<BleDevice> scanResultList) {
                Log.e(TAG, "onScanFinished: " + scanResultList.size());
            }
        });
```

Comment: Do you have related permission declared in Manifest?

Comment: Yes, I have apply these permission.  ```<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN" />

 <uses-feature
  android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth_le"
  android:required="true" />```